found duplicate lang item `panic_impl` the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `once_cell` depends on)
I'm trying to build polkadot-solochain-template with some customizations and got this error:
error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `panic_impl`
      --> /home/viktor/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-1949cf8c6b5b557f/sp-io-38.0.0/src/lib.rs:1775:1
       |
  1775 | / pub fn panic(info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
  1776 | |     let message = alloc::format!("{}", info);
  1777 | |     #[cfg(feature = "improved_panic_error_reporting")]
  ...    |
  1786 | | }
       | |_^
       |
       = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `once_cell` depends on)
       = note: first definition in `std` loaded from /home/viktor/projects/polkadot-sdk-solochain-template/target/release/wbuild/solochain-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libstd-61957e3233a6776a.rmeta
       = note: second definition in the local crate (`sp_io`)

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0152`.
  error: could not compile `sp-io` (lib) due to 1 previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

My rustup show:
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/viktor/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2022-03-17-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-03-17-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2022-08-03-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2022-12-19-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-12-19-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2023-01-09-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2023-03-25-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2024-06-21-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2024-08-30-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
1.61.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.76.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.81.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.70-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (directory override for '/home/viktor/projects/polkadot-sdk-solochain-template')
rustc 1.85.0-nightly (7c002ff9a 2024-12-25)

I've checked my .toml files and all of my dependencies have default-features = false and included to the [std] section. Also I've added #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)] to my lib.rs.
What other problem could there be? Maybe I missed something? BTW, I don't have once_cell crate in my dependencies.

The solution for me was to change Cargo.toml in [std] section.
I added to all dependencies in [std] section ? like this
Changed this pallet-name/std to this pallet-name?/std and after that fixed all errors related to std in dependency.
